# IntelliJ cannot resolve resources nor AndroidManifest.xml in SBT (multi)project

Tags: android, intellij-idea, sbt, android-sdk-plugin

Ever since I've migrated Android project from Gradle to SBT I become unable to work effectively with resources:

- each symbol within XML resources (e.g. `@string/app_name`) is highlighted red and displays error message (e.g. `Cannot resolve '@string/app_name' symbol`),
- layouts editors fail to work as all variables in layouts are unresolved, so I cannot effectively edit them,

What is more IDE reports that `AndroidManifest.xml` is missing and so I am unable to run app from within IDE, because I am unable to configure any Run Configuration. Automatic refactoring of manifest and resources where e.g. activity class name is changed also fails.

However, all resources and manifest are in their place. Facets are also set up correctly as it can be seen in the picture:

[image: errors shown by IDE]

**What I already tried and haven't worked**:

- editing facets - all of them are set up correctly,
- invalidating cache and restarting IntelliJ,
- removing `.idea` directory and reimporting project with SBT plugin,
- syncing projects as in Gradle ones - there is no such option for SBT, best I could was was to refresh build.

Normally I would suspect that the build is for some reason not working, but:

- `sbt clean app/android:run` correctly builds application from the scratch and load into the emulated device, where it works as expected,
- facets within IDE are set up correctly, all dependencies are correctly recognized, projects are correctly set up.

What can I try to diagnose/resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable source generation in IDE.

Resources from aar do not resolve in local xml resources, this is currently a limitation of IDEA sbt project import support

Comment: Unfortunately, it only fixed the `generating sources` message. Symbols from resources (in the very same project) are still not resolved, and run configurations cannot locate manifest: http://i.imgur.com/pt3r6UR.png (screenshot made after disabling sources generation and invalidation sources with restart).

Comment: Run configuration must *not* use `Make`; it *must* use `SBT`; and yes, resources will not be resolvable from XML in IDEA, that is a known issue.

Comment: Best I could achieve was to run `app/android:run` SBT task to deploy and start application from IntelliJ. When I try to configure *Android Application* task I still get `AndroidManifest.xml doesn't exists or has incorrect root tag` message - I can replace `Make ` with SBT task like `android:package` and ignore error message - then SBT is run, package is build, but app is not deployed nor started (so debugging from within IDE is impossible). Does this manifest issue also falls into the non-resolvable resources category?

Comment: You must remove the `Make` task, period. Deployment is automatic, as is debug

Comment: I did (http://i.imgur.com/XEfMXU9.png). If ignore the invalid configuration warning (and manually set APK Path to the SBT produced file), then after SBT is done I get `[app] Unable to obtain main package from manifest.` error.

Comment: stack overflow is not a support forum, use the gitter.